# How to delete an element from an Array in userform VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

I have a user form with the following code. Basically what it does is If the user selects a title, and clicks commandButton2 which inserts the selected movie title into a titlebox and an array. Now i made another button commandButton3 which the user can select from the titlebox for which title to delete, but i am struggling deleting it from the array that i am building as well. Thanks in advance.

```
Public SelectedTitles As Variant, ArrCount As Long, EnableEvents As Boolean
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Done Button
    Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'User has indicated they want to add the currently selected item to the list
    If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub
    If ArrCount = 0 Then 'First item, create the array
        SelectedTitles = Array("")
    Else
        ReDim Preserve SelectedTitles(UBound(SelectedTitles) + 1) 'Next items, add one more space in the array
    End If
    
    'Add the selected title to the array
    SelectedTitles(ArrCount) = ComboBox1.Value
    ListBox1.AddItem (SelectedTitles(ArrCount))
    'Increment the counter
    ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
    'Reset the checkbox and the combobox
    EnableEvents = False
    CommandButton2.Value = False
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            ListBox1.RemoveItem i
                If SelectedTitles() = i Then
                    SelectedTitles() = "n/a"
                End If
             ArrCount = ArrCount - 1
        End If
     Next i
     
    EnableEvents = False
    CommandButton3.Value = False
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    ListBox1.Clear
    Erase SelectedTitles
    ArrCount = 0
    EnableEvents = False
    CommandButton4.Value = False
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to copy the array into a new array without the element of choice. Better to look at using collections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object

Comment: Couldn't you populate the array from the listbox?

Comment: @Norie when would i do so. If i were to do so, then i think i would have to put the code i have for Command BUtton 2 in the commandbutton1 which will create the array based off of listbox?

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all, using arrays in VBA can be a real pain. You might consider using ArrayLists instead, which are far more convenient to use. Check this:https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/

Assuming your array was an arraylist you could just do you could just do :

```
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem i
        SelectedTitles.RemoveAt i
    End If
 Next i
```

But if you wish to stick to your array you'll have to do something like this :

```
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem i
           For j = 0 to Ubound(SelectedTitles)-1
              If SelectedTitles(j) <> SelectedTitles (i) then
                 ReDim Preserve TempSelectedTitles(UBound(TempSelectedTitles) + 1)
                 TempSelectedTitles(j) =  SelectedTitles(i)
              end if
           next  J
           SelectedTitles = TempSelectedTitle
    End If
  Next i
```

I didn't try this code but you got the idea, you will need to rebuild your array without including the selected value in you listbox

Comment: Hi @Josselin Jankowski Thanks for helping me! Sadly i dont think i used arraylist, but using the second code you sent  was getting the error "Invalid ReDim" why could this be. Do i have to initialize the TempSelctedTitles. Thank you

Comment: But it sounds like, if i can just change the SelectedTitles array up above in CommandButton2 to an ArrayList, my problems would be solved

Comment: @kyle See [quick guide `ArrayList`](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/)

Comment: @JosselinJankowski Think you could avoid repeated `ReDim Preserve` if you execute it outside the loop.